# After moving my Drupal 7 site to another host, modules are appeared without download

Tags: migration, drupal-7, drupal-modules, database-migration

I'm sorry for such a complex subject. My problem is.

I tried to move my Drupal 7 site from one server to another.
I uploaded a fresh install to my new site.
I backed up my old database and imported to my new site.
I uploaded settings.php file to my new site.

When i entered to my new site's module part, All the 3rd party modules i installed in my old site, exist in my new site without any loss :)
But when i check the folders
/sites/all/modules
/sites/default
/modules
I couldn't find any file regarding to this modules.

Modules exist in my new site when i check my admin panel, I can create content by using this modules, But i can't see their files by using file manager etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you didn't disable the modules before moving your deployment, I think they're still marked in your database, same for registration of content types. As the modules don't actually exist, you won't get their functionality.

Replacing the modules under /sites/all/modules or /sites/default/modules should leave them working as before.

Comment: Thank you. You're right i didn't disable them before deployment.<br/> Yesterday i did the same things, made a refresh Drupal site and import my database. Then i put all the module files to the sites/all/modules folders. Then i started to get "Fatal error, memory was exhausted" error. I talked to my host and they say that they can't increase my memory limit.

Comment: In this case, what I'd do if I were you would be to reintroduce your modules one by one, then you can isolate which one is causing the memory problem. Once you've identified it, there will probably be some answers on the forums.